# Tkitnter canvas widget events

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter gui and I want it to work like this:
I have a frame, inside the frame there's a canvas and inside the canvas there are multiple rectangles

I want to make it that once I hover over a rectangle it's color will change from white, to green
simple, right?

so help me figure out what's wrong

Here's the class:

```
class guiSong:

    def __init__(self, master: tkinter.Canvas, songobject: SongFile, x, y, rect=None):
        self.master = master
        self.songobject = songobject
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = rect

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.master.itemconfig(self.rect, fill='green')
        print("Should change to green rect ", str(self.rect))

    def on_leave(self, enter):
        self.master.itemconfig(self.rect, fill='white')

    def display(self):
        self.rect = self.master.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 1150, self.y + 150, fill='white', tags = ['playbutton',self.songobject])
        print("Self Rect is "+str(self.rect)+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        self.master.tag_bind('playbutton',"<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.master.tag_bind('playbutton',"<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.albumimg = Image.open(BytesIO(self.songobject.albumimage))
        self.albumimg = ImageOps.expand(self.albumimg,border=5)
        self.albumimg = self.albumimg.resize((120, 120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.albumimg)
        make_image(self.img, self.x + 25, self.y + 15, self.master)
        print(f"Creating image {str(self.img)} at x",self.x+25, " y ",self.y+15 )
        return self.img
        #self.master.create_image(self.x + 25, self.y + 15, anchor = tkinter.W,image=img)
```

Don't bother the whole songobject stuff that's unrelated

I made a list of those objects and displayed them all inside a canvas one after another
The expected output is that once I hover over a rectangle it'll turn green
what happens in reality is that only the last rectangle created is colored once hovering over any rectangle.

Comment: You should use `self.rect` instead of `'playbutton'` in `self.master.tag_bind(...)`, i.e. `self.master.tag_bind(self.rect, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, it's a rectangle that becomes green when you hover it with mouse, red when you leave it, and blue if you click on it.

Note : for `blue` color, I made an example with an argument in the callback function.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.can = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, height=200)
        self.can.pack()
        self.rect = self.can.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill="gray")

        self.can.tag_bind(self.rect, '<Enter>', self.green_rect)       
        self.can.tag_bind(self.rect, '<Leave>', self.red_rect)       
        self.can.tag_bind(self.rect, '<Button-1>', lambda x:self.color_rect("blue"))             

    def color_rect(self, color):
        self.can.itemconfigure(self.rect, fill=color)

    def green_rect(self, event=None):
        self.can.itemconfigure(self.rect, fill="green")

    def red_rect(self, event=None):
        self.can.itemconfigure(self.rect, fill="red")

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each rectangle is an instance of `guiSong`, you can directly bind to the canvas item rather than to a tag.

Here's a simplified version of your class:

```
class guiSong:
    def __init__(self, master, songobject, x, y):
        self.master = master
        tags = ("playbutton", songobject)
        self.rect = master.create_rectangle(x,y,x+100, y+100, tags=tags, fill="white")
        self.master.tag_bind(self.rect, "<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.master.tag_bind(self.rect, "<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.master.itemconfigure(self.rect, fill="red")

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.master.itemconfigure(self.rect, fill="white")
```

If you wish to bind to the tag, you can use the tag "current" to refer to the object that received the event.

```
class guiSong:
    ...
    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.master.itemconfigure("current", fill="red")

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.master.itemconfigure("current", fill="white")
```